# Best practices for using SendGrid's v3 API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates, sendgrid-ruby

I'm using the v3 API to send confirmation emails to my new users. All of the emails appear to be sending BUT over half of the emails don't contain the dynamically-inserted confirmation URL that I send along in the request.

I'm not sure where to start debugging this: if ~50% of the emails are getting the links within their emails and the rest aren't, where would you start with digging into this problem?

Comment: Can you tell if there's any difference between the emails and the emails without, besides the links? (for example, time sent, user account delivered to, application that makes the send request?)

Comment: @MiloPsupportsGoFundMonica, I migrated our site over to SendGrid today... and I can't seem to find a pattern just yet. It's just random that some work and others don't.

For the record, this particular method is using the same template ID for all the emails. The request that we're sending off to SendGrid is formed the same way each time.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. You haven't told us enough to help you without shooting in the dark.